# absolute vertical centering elements

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've tried a lot of methods to center the children elements absolute vertical center but couldn't be success with any techniques.

[Here's one example what I've tried](http://jsfiddle.net/odo1gkqf/):

html (cannot change) :

```
<div class="foo">
    <h1>blah blah</h1>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.foo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
.foo:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Please note: I cannot change the markup i.e I cannot wrap `.foo` with parent div and even cannot wrap all childrens within `.foo` with a div.

So, how can I vertically center them over the full window ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the css [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) layout like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/crhvsgeb/)**

```css
.foo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* align-items: center; */
}
h1, p {
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <h1>blah blah</h1>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But what about the older browsers?

Comment: @C-linkNepal Yeah! It doesn't support older browsers but IE10+ is still good (IMO) cause it's a very good feature. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

Make the `.foo` element a table, and every child a `table-row`.

Then add an `after` and `before` pseudo elements, also as rows, forcing them to expand with `min-height: 100%;`.

The inner elements will then squeeze in the middle:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/odo1gkqf/3/)

```css
.foo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    display: table;
}

.foo:before, .foo:after {
    content: "";
    display: table-row;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.foo > * {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <h1>blah blah</h1>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a great solution and i will keep this in mind!